# Function to insert an integer into a circular linked _list in ascending order

Tags: data-structures

I am writing a function to insert an integer into a circular linked _list in ascending order whose elements are sorted in ascending order (smallest to largest).

The input to the function insertSortedList is a pointer start to some node in the circular list and an integer n between 0 and 100. Return a pointer to the newly inserted node.

The structure to follow for a node of the circular linked list is-

```
Struct CNode;
Typedef struct CNode cnode;
Struct CNode
{
   Int  value;
   Cnode* next;
};
Cnode* insertSortedList (cnode* start,int n)
{
   //WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
}
//FUNCTION SIGNATURE ENDS

Test Case 1:
Input:
[3->4->6->1->2->^],5
Expected Return Value:
[5->6->1->2->3->4->^]

Test Case  2:
Input:
[1->2->3->4->5->^],0
Expected Return Value:
[0->1->2->3->4->5->^]
```

Here's my code:

```
 Cnode* insertSortedList (cnode* start,int n)
 {
 int count=1,i,count1=0;
 Cnode* temp=start;
 Cnode* temp1=start;
 Cnode* temp2=start;
 Cnode* newHead=NULL;

while(temp!=NULL)
 {
temp=temp->next;
count ++;
}

int arr[count];

while(temp2!=NULL)
 {
    for(j=0;j<count;j++)
    {
        arr[j]=temp->data;
        temp2=temp2->next;
     }
}


while(n>=temp2->value)
{
    temp2=temp2->next;
 }

 newHead=temp2;

 for(i=0;i<count;i++)
 {
    Cnode* newNode=new Cnode();

    newNode->data=arr[i];
    newNode->next=NULL;
 }

}
```

Comment: What did you try? You don't expect us to do your homework for you. We can help if you have a specific question.

Comment: i'have posted my code . Now can you please help!

Comment: You need to tell us which language you are using. Don't leave us to guess!

Comment: You didn't even state what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

You said it's a circular linked-list but you are checking for `temp != null`. It should be `temp→next != start`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not so complicated at all. Given a pointer to any element in a circular linked list, whose elements are already in ascending order, we just need to find the location of the new element, which can be done in a few lines. Simple Java code -

```
CNode prev = start;
CNode next = start.next;

while(true){
    if(prev.value <= n && n <= next.value) break;
    prev=next; next=next.next;
}

CNode node = new CNode();
node.value = n;
prev.next=node; node.next=next;

return node;
```